# ¿Se puede parsear HTML con expresiones regulares?

Tags: html, regex

Ayer [traduje](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/90030/83) la respuesta de [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1983854) con su famoso fragmento de código:

> No puedes parsear [X]HTML con expresiones regulares porque el HTML no se puede parsear con regex. Regex no es una herramienta que se pueda usar para parsear correctamente HTML. Como ya he contestado muchas preguntas de HTML y regex, el uso de regex no te permitirá procesar HTML. Las expresiones regulares son una herramienta que no es lo suficientemente sofisticada para entender las construcciones utilizadas por el HTML. HTML no es un lenguaje regular y, por tanto, no puede analizarse sintácticamente mediante expresiones regulares. Las expresiones regulares no están equipadas para diseccionar el HTML en sus partes representativas.

que acaba con una demostración final de HTML roto:

> aparece<strike>, la pestilente inf</strike>ección de regex dev​**orará tu parser de HT**​ML, tu aplicación y tu existencia para siempre como un mero Visual Basic o peor *él viene* no *luc*hes él**viene v̡im̡ie̶ne, ̕h̵u** radiaccio͞n destr*yendo҉ toda  lumi̍̈́̂̈́nosidad, las etiquetas de HTML **filtra͠ndo de  ̡tu​͟s ojos̸ ̛como líq**ido d*oloroso, la canción de parsear expresi<strike>ones re̸gulares</strike> va a exti*nguir las voces del hombre mor​**tal  de la esf/b>era  puedo verlo puede ̲͚̖͔̙ver e*s hermos**o el final extinguiendo las mentiras de los Hombres TO*****DO EŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́TÁ PERDIDO TODO EST**Á PE*****RDI**DO e*l pon̷y él vie*ne él v<strike>iene él vien</strike>**<strike>e el</strike> íco*r pe*rme**a to*do M*I CARA M*I CARA ᵒh dos n**o **o NO NOO̼*******O​O N**Θ para l*os án​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆ul͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨo*s ͎ n​o son rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆es ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ESͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ ALȳ̳ Ë͖́̉L ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘L ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬViENȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝"

Yo di por buenas sus aseveraciones:

- HTML no se puede parsear con regex
- las regex no son lo suficientemente sofisticadas para este cometido
- HTML no es un lenguaje regular y, por tanto, no se puede analizar sintácticamente con expresiones regulares.

Pero a continuación recibí un [comentario de Mariano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90027/modificar-enlaces-que-contienen-una-imagen/90030#comment165588_90030):

> Sé que esto es un chiste que se hizo famoso. No obstante, "HTML no se puede parsear con regex" es falso. "no es lo suficientemente sofisticada" es falso. "no están equipadas para diseccionar el HTML" es falso. "no es un lenguaje regular y, por tanto, no puede analizarse sintácticamente mediante expresiones regulares" es rotundamente falso. Lo que es verdad es que te va a traer dolores de cabeza, porque no es una herramienta que se ajuste a ese trabajo... Odio esta publicación.

Y me quedé dudando. Búsquedas posteriores me llevaron una entrada de blog de Jeff Atwood [*Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/), de 2009, donde empieza hablando de la respuesta que acabo de citar, mostrando el sentimiento que la generó. Sin embargo, *parsea* el estado de la cuestión y muestra que tampoco es tan claro que no se pueda. Menciona [una discusión](http://www.metafilter.com/86689/So-does-anyone-know-how-to-make-an-HTML-regex-parser) en la que programadores experimentados defienden su uso en ciertos casos.

Por tanto, la duda es:

- ¿Se puede parsear un HTML con expresiones regulares?
- ¿En qué casos es recomendable hacerlo?
- ¿En qué casos es desaconsejable?

<sub>Se habrá notado que uso *parsear* y *analizar sintácticamente* indistintamente. Lo hago pues una parece la traducción de la otra, pero no es menos cierto que en entornos hispanohablantes el uso de *parsear* está muy extendido.</sub>

Comment: se que depende de lo que vas a hacer pero puedes hacer un xsd(quedaria construido mas o menos como tu expresion regular) y lo mezcla con el html, obviamente tu pregunta es usando expresion regular pero si deseas realizarlo de otra forma te propongo esto

Comment: Con una sola expresión, claro que NO, pero Si muchas. Algunas ves la hice. Tuve mi código que lo usaba, sin embargo; mi disco duro se averió, incluyendo las de las copias.. :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

La primera cuestión es saber a qué nos referimos con "parsear HTML".

La interpretación estricta es procesar el documento, comprobar que es un HTML correcto, trabajar con la totalidad del documento, etc. En ese sentido, **las expresiones regulares son completamente insuficientes**.

El ejemplo clásico es el de elementos que se puedan anidar indefinidamente. Si empiezo a hacer `<div><div><div>....<div>Hola mundo</div>....</div></div></div>`, no hay ninguna expresión regular que pueda verificar que he abierto el mismo número de `div` que he cerrado (fuente: teoría de autómatas finitos).

Ahora bien, aquí es cuando alguien entra y dice: "Pero yo no estoy construyendo un navegador web/analizador gramatical. Yo lo que quiero saber es qué pone dentro del `div`. Me da igual que se cierren todos los tags o no, eso es problema de quien genera el HTML. Para mí, **las expresiones regulares son completamente suficientes**."

Naturalmente, si hay cambios en el HTML, las expresiones regulares son mucho más frágiles. El problema no es tanto que fallen<sup>1</sup> como que den falsos positivos.

Por ejemplo, tenemos nuestra expresión para encontrar el contenido del `<div>`(`<div>(.*)<\/div>`), y de repente la página nos cambia a:

```
 <div>Hola mundo<!-- Tonto el que lo lea!!--></div>
```

Vaya... mejor lo cambiamos a (`<div>(.*)<`), ¿no? Bueno, hasta que nos llega:

```
 <div>Hola <a href="http://micasa.example">mundo</a></div>
```

Bueno, lo solucionamos (ya no pongo la expresión regular), y a la semana siguiente tenemos

```
 <!-- <div>Hola mundo</div> No lo borro, solo lo comento porque no me fío del SVN. Firmado: el novato -->
 <div>Adios mundo</div>
```

En todos los casos de arriba, la expresión regular se come el error como si nada y el proceso sigue hasta que alguien (posiblemente un humano) se da cuenta de que los valores no casan, quizás semanas o meses después<sup>2</sup>.

Así que:

> ¿Se puede parsear un HTML con expresiones regulares?

En general, **NO**.

> ¿En qué casos es recomendable hacerlo?

Más que "recomendable", no es demasiado problema cuando:

- El origen del HTML está controlado. Es un programa mío, o es alguien de mi organización que me avisará cuando vaya a haber un cambio.
- También relacionado con lo anterior, sabemos qué estructura tendrá. Si sabemos que va a ser un documento tal que:

  ```
  <html><body>
  <ul>
  <li>Punto 1.</li>
  <li>Punto 2.</li>
  ...
  </ul>
  ```

  y que no se van a meter tags ni comentarios ni JavaScript por en medio, no hay problema<sup>3</sup>

> ¿En qué casos es desaconsejable?

Todos los demás.

---

<sup>1</sup> Si falla, se procesa el error y se adapta la expresión regular adecuadamente. Al fin y al cabo, si el formato de la página que se parsea cambia, también los programas que usen analizadores gramaticales pueden tener problemas (aunque siempre serán más flexibles).

<sup>2</sup> Una clase de problema distinto sería si quiero obtener el contenido del primer `div` y me mueven el contenido al tercero. Pero eso es irresoluble tanto para regexp como parseadores a no ser que se use `id` en los elementos; y si se usa `id` lo que se busca no es el n-ésimo `div` sino el elemento con el `id` correspondiente.

<sup>3</sup> De hecho, el subconjunto de HTML así definido es en realidad un lenguaje regular, por lo que las expresiones regulares son completamente suficientes para analizarlo por completo.

Comment: Qué respuesta tan bien construida y expuesta, SJuan. Por lo que parece, las conclusiones de Jeff Atwood en 2009 en el artículo del blog se mantienen: usa regex para casos específicos y conocidos. El resto es levedad.

Comment: Excelente respuesta y divertida. Yo le añadiría: si quieres parsear html una mejor solución y no digo que perfecta o libre de errores sería utilizar las tecnologías XML (XSL=>XPATH,XSLT,XSL:FO). Al final de cuantas un html es un xml, por eso surgió xhtml.