# Obtener todos los textos sin etiquetas html y/o PHP con regex

Tags: html, regex

Estoy buscando crear una expresión regular para obtener los textos que no contengan etiquetas html y/o PHP dentro de un string.

```
<div class="my_class">
     <div class="copy">
       © 2018 Texto
     </div>
   </div>
```

Hasta ahora, tengo la siguiente expresión regular

```
[^\s<\?ph?(h2|a ref="#")>].+\w+((?=<)|[^</*>]$)
```

pero aún esta incompleta, ya que, si agrego lo siguiente no funciona:

```
<div class="my_class">
 <h1>¿como estas?</h1>
 <div class="copy">
   © 2018 Texto
 </div>
```

```
<?php
      $valor = $CI->session->getSessionData('Mivalor');
 ?>
```

no selecciona "¿como estas?" y "session->getSessionData('Mivalor');
     ?>"

Comment: Y aparte, puedes revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90347/se-puede-parsear-html-con-expresiones-regulares

Comment: Cuando haces una pregunta sobre expresiones regulares, conviene especificar el lenguaje de programación o herramienta utilizado. html no sería válido en este contexto. Quizás te refieras a javascript o a php. Por favor, podrías editar la pregunta y añadir el detalle? Gracias.

Comment: Cómo quieres considerar estos casos: `<div>hola <b>mundo</b></div>`?

Comment: @Julio es genérico, solo estoy construyendo un literal que pueda leer un string con etiquetas html y que luego me gustaría pasarlo a php.  Además quiero considerar todos los casos, obtener todos los valores que no sean etiquetas html.

Comment: Te valdría con eliminar todas las etiquetas del fuente?

Comment: Igual sirve, de todas formas quiero todo lo que no sea etiqueta

Comment: No está claro el lenguaje que usa la expresión regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente: `<(script|style)[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>|<\/?[^>]+>`

Reemplazar por: `(nada)`

**Explicado:**

```
  # Primera opción: Eliminamos todas las parejas de etiquetas script y style
  #                 Se entiende que su contenido no se considera texto
  <(script|style)[^>]*> # Inicio de etiqueta script/style. Guardamos en primer grupo de captura. Pueden preceder otras cosas como atributos.
    [\s\S]*?  # Cualquier caracter 0 o más veces, con 'pereza'
  <\/\1>      # Cierre de etiqueta (debe ser igual que primer grupo de captura)
# Segunda opción. Eliminar cualquier etiqueta
# < + /(opcional) + cualquier caracter que no sea > 1 o más veces + >
|<\/?[^>]+>
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n1ClF2/2/)**

Comment: Edite la pregunta nuevamente, ya que, tenia un código php que no me lo captura la expresión.

Comment: Hola @Xavy. No he entendido si la respuesta te ha llegado a funcionar o no. En caso negativo, ¿puedes pasar un ejemplo con el que no funcione? Gracias

Comment: Estimado @Julio ese es un ejemplo de que no captura todo el texto `<?php
      $valor = $CI->session->getSessionData('Mivalor');
 ?>`

Comment: Eso no son etiquetas html como decías en la pregunta original. Quizás podrías editar la pregunta y poner un par de casos de ejemplo de entrada vs resultado esperado