# ¿Cómo extraer links de emails con Google App Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, gmail

Necesito extraer los link que contengan los mensajes, así como se muestra en la imagen.

[image]

[image: imagen]

```
function importReport() {



var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox label:Terrorismo newer: 2019/04/13')
var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('id'); 


  for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {

    var body= msgs[i][j].getBody();
    //extraer link 


  }


  }
```

El actual código, recorre todos los mensajes que tengan la etiqueta Terrorismo y sean actuales, ahora necesito extraerlas y luego almacenarlas en un excel (esta parte la tengo cubierta).

Necesito ayuda para conseguir el objetivo , cualquier comentario lo pondré en practica e investigare, muchas gracias

*El cuerpo de la pagina esta estructurada con una "application/json" y de este quiero extraer los"widgets"--->"url": "https://www.google.com/url?rct=j\u0026sa=t\u0026url=https://diariocorreo.pe...."

Con debugger  obtube el siguiente resultado de la variable "body"

```
    <html lang="es-PE"> <head> </head> <body> <div>  <script data-scope="inboxmarkup" type="application/json">{

  "api_version": "1.0",

  "publisher": {

    "api_key": "",

    "name": "Google Alerts"

  },

  "entity": {

    "external_key": "Alerta de Google: policia detiene",

    "title": "Alerta de Google: policia detiene",

    "subtitle": "Más reciente: 13 de abril de 2019",

    "avatar_image_url": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/gsa_512dp.png",

    "main_image_url": "https://www.gstatic.com/bt/C3341AA7A1A076756462EE2E5CD71C11/smartmail/mobile/il_newspaper_header_r1.png"

  },

  "updates": {

    "snippets": [ {

      "icon": "BOOKMARK",

      "message": "En Tumán detienen a un policía acusado de lesiones e intento de violación sexual"

    } ]

  },

  "cards": [ {

    "title": "Alerta de Google: policia detiene",

    "subtitle": "Resultados destacados del correo electrónico más reciente",

    "actions": [ {

      "name": "Ver más resultados",

      "url": "https://www.google.com.pe/alerts?s=AB2Xq4g-LZwPzYR-SvveKmDOlNR52e5azx94F9I\u0026start=1555127384\u0026end=1555170897\u0026source=alertsmail\u0026hl=es\u0026gl=PE\u0026msgid=MTI4NjU1OTg3NDA1MDkxNDA5NDQ#history"

    } ],

    "widgets": [ {

      "type": "LINK",

      "title": "En Tumán detienen a un policía acusado de lesiones e intento de violación sexual",

      "description": "Por una grave acusación un agente de la Policía Nacional del Perú fue detenido por sus pares, pues fue denunciado por agredir violentamente a dos ...",

      "url": "https://www.google.com/url?rct=j\u0026sa=t\u0026url=https://diariocorreo.pe/edicion/lambayeque/en-tuman-detienen-un-policia-acusado-de-lesiones-e-intento-de-violacion-sexual-881393/\u0026ct=ga\u0026cd=CAEYACoUMTI4NjU1OTg3NDA1MDkxNDA5NDQyHzM2ZjUzNjE1YmMyOWNlNGQ6Y29tLnBlOmVzOlBFOlI\u0026usg=AFQjCNFU_ZCUUKf2IGf8cBAFs6Y7Obqw7w"

    } ]

  } ]
```

Comment: No se entiende bien qué es lo que quieres extraer, ¿el link de la noticia que viene en la alerta? Si es así, ¿has pensado en usar mejor la API de Google News directamente?

Comment: No está claro como obtuviste el código que has agregado a la pregunta. Por favor agrega un [mcve].

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tu aportacion, estoy investigando sobre esa api

Comment: No publiques tu API KEY en la pregunta.

Comment: @Rubén gracias por la recomendacion, ya edite mi pregunta, el segundo fragmento de codigo me lo trae la instruccion--> var body msgs[i][j].getBody();

Comment: `var body msgs[i][j].getBody()` no tiene una sintaxis correcta, faltaría el operador de asignación (`=`) por otro lado siguen sin estar claro cómo obtuviste lo que agregaste a la pregunta, ( Logger, Stackdriver, debugger, ...) Es por ello que deberías agregar un [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén disculpa si no me deje entender, el primer fragmento de codigo me devuelve con debugger en la variable "body" el segundo framento de tipo "application/json", de esto quisiera extraer : el json "widgets" -->'url'

Answer (score 1):

En relación al título original de la pregunta, el primer comentario es que se trata de Google Apps Script, no de Google Apps Engine, en particular porque el código incluido en la pregunta usa Google Apps Script.

El segundo comentario es que deberías intentar leer la documentación en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/, en particular tratar de entender el código del ejemplo incluido en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getBody():

```
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Obtener el primer thread en la bandeja de entrada
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Obtener el primer mensaje
Logger.log(message.getBody()); // Registrar el contenido del cuerpo del mensaje
```

Verás que `getBody` devuelve el HTML del cuerpo del mensaje, así que para obtener los enlaces debarás aprender a "parsear" HTML para extraer de este el atributo `href` de las etiquetas `a`

El tercer comentario, luego de la revisión 11 de la pregunta, es que lo anterior sobre aprender a parsear HTML sigue siendo válido. Podrías primero extraer la cadena del JSON, luego usar `JSON.parse(cadena)` para convertirlo en un objeto y posteriormente usar los métodos propios de JavaScript para extraer ls propiedades de tu interés , que en est caso serían los objetos del array `widjets` y de estos las propiedades `url`.

Relacionado

- [¿Se puede parsear HTML con expresiones regulares?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90347/65)

Referencias

- [Trabajando con JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta e indagado por sus sugerencias, e actualizado mi post con el contenido que me devuelve el .getBody(); ,y este es una "application/json"

Comment: @DannaLucianaCarrilloPerez Actualicé mi respuesta.