# Trocear fichero cuyo contenido son varios ficheros concatenados xml y está en una sola línea (LINUX)

Tags: linux, xml, split, awk

tengo un fichero que contiene varios ficheros xml concatenados, y el contenido está en una sola línea.

Ejemplo:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ml:individual xmlns:ml=http://www.ex xmlns><id>...........</ml:sample> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ml:individual xmlns:ml="ht" <id>...........</ml:sample> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ml:individual xmlns:ml="htt" ><id>...........</ml:sample>`

El resultado deseado serían tres ficheros de la siguiente forma:

fichero1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ml:individual xmlns:ml=http://www.ex > 
<id>....
....
...
</ml:sample>
```

fichero2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ml:individual xmlns:ml="ht" 
<id>....
....
...
</ml:sample>
```

fichero3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ml:individual xmlns:ml="htt" >
<id>....
....
...
</ml:sample>
```

He probado con esto:

```
awk 'BEGIN {NUM=0}; /xml version="1.0"/ {NUM++; filename=NUM".xml"}; {print >filename}' fichero.xml
```

pero no funciona porque el fichero inicial está en una sola línea.

¿Alguna sugerancia?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si `awk` es la mejor herramienta para esto, pero una forma es configurar el separador de registros con el texto de inicio de cada archivo:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="<?xml version";NFILE=0}{filename=NFILE".xml";if (NFILE >0) print RS substr($0, 1, length($0)-2)>filename; NFILE++}' fichero.xml
```

Con esto, cada archivo representará una línea, la primer línea se ignora por que será vacía.

Otra forma, para mi gusto más óptima, es usar `sed` para agregar un `\n` dónde comienza cada archivo, y luego simplemente con `split` generar archivos por cada línea:

```
sed -r "s/(.)(<\?xml)/\1\n\2/g" fichero.xml | split -a 2 -d -l 1 --additional-suffix=.xml - archivo_
```

Comment: Parece que esta es una pregunta para traer [ESTO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/236345).

Comment: @Alfabravo cierto, mejor usar herramientas específicas. Así y todo, para este caso concreto funciona. Por cierto, le hicimos un homenaje a esa publicación [aquí en SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90347/83)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!. Funciona perfectamente.