# Expresion regular para eliminar comentarios JS, HTML y CSS

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex

Necesito una expresión regular que funcione para eliminar comentarios de HTML, JS y CSS.

El mayor problema con el que me encuentro es en los comentarios de línea. Como en el proyecto en el que trabajo hay mucho JS a fuego en HTML, si intento detectar // hasta final de línea, también matchea urls.

Aun así, eso lo solucioné con esta:

```
/((?<!(\:))(\/\/)(.|\s)*?(\n))/g
```

Pero no es suficiente, ya que puede haber una url tipo `src="//jquery.etc"` y se la carga también.

Con esta lo solucioné:

```
/(?<=\")((?<!(\:))(\/\/)(.|\s)*?(\n))(?=\")/g
```

Pero ahora me encuentro con el problema de que a veces (por razones que desconozco) puede haber algo delante de esas dos barras. Ej: `src="algo//jquery.etc"`

**¿Cómo puedo detectar directamente si está encapsulado para que no se elimine?**

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Todo un clásico del sition en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/598289

Comment: @SJuan76 que [incorporé a SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/90030/83) hace un tiempo :)

Answer (score 1):

Deberías intentar encontrar los tags relevantes primero:

En Javascript (texto que encuentres entre `<script>` y `</script>`) encontrarás comentarios de dos tipos:

```
//esto es un comentario de una línea
/*Esto es un comentario en bloque, puede tener o no
  varias líneas*/
```

Si no estoy equivocado, en un bloque de código CSS (`<style> ...</style>`) puedes encontrar comentarios así:

```
h1 {
  /*color: red; comentado*/
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Pero no se admiten comentarios con `//`, eso produce un error de sintaxis.

Y, por último, HTML usa para comentar código lo siguiente:

```
<p> Esto es un párrafo <!-- Esto es un comentario --> </p>
```

Existe una excepción, que es cuando metes estilos como atributos, ya que es código CSS, pero no es habitual verlos:

```
<p style="color: red; /*el color es rojo*/"> ...</p>
```

Así que yo intentaría lo siguiente: Buscar primero las etiquetas que definen el inicio y fin de cada lenguaje y entonces buscar los comentarios  que correspondan y eliminarlos

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentarlo con estas expresiones regulares:

```
<?php
// Eliminar comentarios html
$txt = preg_replace('/\h*<!--.*?-->\h*/s', '', $txt);

// Eliminar comentarios /* */
$txt = preg_replace('/\h*\/\*.*?\*\/\h*/s', '', $txt);

// Eliminar comentarios //
$txt = preg_replace('/^\h*(?|(.*"[^"]*\/\/[^"]*".*)|(.*)\/\/.*\h*)$/m', '$1', $txt);
```

[Aquí](https://www.ideone.com/qYe2EW) tienes un ejemplo en funcionamiento